# Mediaelement.js progress bar (Wordpress and Firefox)

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

In the demo version of mediaelement.js, the audio player works perfectly on Firefox (Mac) with an MP3 but when using the MediaElement Wordpress plugin, the progress bar does not work.

Note that the beta 3.6 version of wordpress, the MediaElement player is integrated directly and the progress bar does not work either on Firefox.

Any line of thought will be very welcome :)